# Why location of log File specified in File appender is not being changed?

Tags: logging, log4j, weblogic

I am using log4j.xml in weblogic. I have specified path in the `file` param of `FileAppender` as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration >
    <appender name="file1" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="D:\ReadText_File\info.txt" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}]- %l - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
       <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
            <param name="LevelToMatch" value="INFO"/>
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
        </filter>    
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
    </appender>

    <logger name="Client.class" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="file1" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="file1" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Now as you can see I have given a path for creating a log file; so instead of creating file in
**`ReadText_File`** folder, It creates the desired file in **`wls12120\user_projects\domains\mydomain\`** and named it **`ReadText_Fileinfo.txt`**

Comment: Have you followed instructions like those here? http://phillips4jc.blogspot.com/2012/01/configuring-web-logic-1035-and-log4j.html Also - is the D: drive a mounted network drive that weblogic can see?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Sir; 
but a very small thing leaded to all this crap
Just used forward slash instead of back slash  in the path; that's it! and everything's working perfectly now.

Comment: Ah yes, good old windows. The other option is probably to change it to ` \\ ` instead of just a single ` \ `. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very small thing leaded to all this crap;
Just tried using forward slash **"/"** instead of back slash **"\"** in the path; that's it!
and everything's working perfectly now.